# Mysterious behavior in try-except-finally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

Excuse the vague title, I didn't know how else to state this.

I have a task worker request handler that fetches data from a URL and writes it to blobstore and saves the data's blob_key to a ListProperty in datastore. I've tried to simplifly the code for clarity here:

```
class Fetch(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        url = self.request.get('url')
        itemKey = self.request.get('itemKey')
        item = MyModel.get(itemKey)

        try:
            result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url)
            if result.status_code == 200:
                saveDataResult = save_data(result.content, itemKey)
                if saveDataResult is False:
                    raise Exception('error saving data')
            else:
                raise Exception('error fetching data: %s' % result.status_code)

            item.status = 'success'
        except Exception:
            item.status = 'failed'
        finally:
            item.put()

def save_data(data, itemKey)
    try:
        #write data to blobstore and get its blob_key...
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
        item = MyModel.get(itemKey)
        item.blobKey.append(blob_key)
        item.put()

        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Now the problem I'm having is, when saveDataResult returns True, its status is set to 'success' but its blobKey property contains no value, even though a blob_key was generated and the data successfully written. I can't see what's causing this to save my life, please help.

Comment: You haven't shown the part where `blob_key` (not `item.blobKey`) gets a value... or maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I've added it but I that can't be it because save_data would return False if blob_key can't be gotten. I'm fairly sure that is not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Without much more information it is very difficult to determine what's happening.  Here's my educated guess:

`MyModel.get(itemKey)` is called both in `get()` and `save_data()`. I surmise that it's returning two different objects representing the item. When the blobKey gets updated in `save_data`, the update is occurring only in the object fetched in `save_data`. When you later examine it outside that scope, you're looking at a different object.

Whether this is correct or not will depend on the implementation of `MyModel.get()`.

Also, you do realize that you're calling `item.put()` twice, right?

Comment: So I guess I should pass the instance of item from get() to save_data as a param? I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
finally:
    item.put()
```

this single call overrides the data saved by `save_data()` because it references an older object of item.

My suggestion would be you do the status updates from `save_data()` i.e  `item.status = 'success'`
or move `item = MyModel.get(itemKey)` to come after `save_data()` so you can fetch the updated object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `save_data()` with `item = MyModel.get(itemKey)`
which is again called from the class Fetch you end up having two different objects and therefore overwriting the one in save_data() and hence when you go to your model datastore no data for blobkey is stored as its overwritten.

Try doing everything in the class or you do not use `item = MyModel.get(itemKey)` twice.